# PHP Send Email to multiple recipients even if one of the recepient is Invalid

Tags: php, email

I am able to send email to multiple recipients by using the mail() function in PHP with the email addresses separated by (,).

But this function is failing if any of the email in the list is Invalid. So the only option I have is to loop and invoke mail() function multiple times causing delay in response.

Greatly Appreciate your help in resolving this issue.

---

Guys,its still an issue. The issue is if the email is not a legitimate one though the format is correct. eg: if 'google@yahoo.com' is part of the mail list, then the mail function is failing without even sending mails to the others in the list.

Issue is with the validity of the email provided and NOT with the syntax.

Comment: the delay should be minimal in the loop (how many are you sending to) also mail() is not that great best to use a third party library that directly connects to the mail server.

Comment: Guys,its still an issue. Thanks Yosi for your suggestion but the issue is if the email is not a legitimate one though the format is correct. eg: if 'google@yahoo.com' is part of the mail list, then the mail function is failing without even sending mails to the others in the list.

Answer (score 0):

A simple filter would suffice:

```
function MYFILTERS_emails($val){
    return !!(filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
}

$emails = implode(', ', array_filter($emails, 'MYFILTERS_emails'));
```

[Working Example](http://ideone.com/OrJgAC)

Comment: Guys, its nt the problem with invalid syntax. I have said this many times.. example : if my list contains mails like, xyz@ge.com,abc@sa.com,<valid email>.PHP mail function is failing since one & two are invalid and not sending the mail to valid email

Comment: @user1613102 xyz@ge.com & abc@sa.com are valid email addresses - PHP doesn't determine whether or not they are "in use" and it doesn't care either, it simply fires-and-forgets.  I'm afraid your problem lies elsewhere.  By default the binary program that sends mail is aptly named `sendmail` - it simply returns a boolean as to whether it handles the request, it doesn't provide feedback on undelivered messages or bounces.  How many emails are you trying to send in one go? - by default I believe there is a 100 recipients cap - you may need to implement some kind of batch system.

Answer (score 0):

This can only happen, if your server (mail program, i.e. sendmail, postfix or the like, look at your PHP's configuration) has a blacklist for non-existing mail addresses (or something equivalent).

The normal behavior of the PHP mail() function is to delegate the mail and list of recipients to the mail program, and to report, whether or not the data was accepted. The return value of mail() does not tell anything about the success of delivery.

Knowing this, there are two possible solutions:

1. Re-configure the mail programm to accept those addresses. Or,
2. Check the existence of the mail address before calling mail() by checking the MX record for the recipient addresses.

Answer (score -1):

You're going to have to loop through the email addresses with any solution to this, however you don't have to use the mail every time.

Loop through the email list and check the validity or each, and remove accordingly and then use your original mail() fx with the clear list.

PHP: (email list as array - $emails)

```
$cleanList = '';
foreach($emails as $email){

    //REGEX email verify
if (eregi("^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+.[a-z]{2,6}$", $email)) {
    $cleanList .= $email.',';
}

//Remove last comma
$cleanList = substr($cleanList,0,-1);
```

main()....

Comment: Don't use depreciated ereg (for anything), and don't use regular expressions at all to validate email addresses when there are filters (http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

Comment: Guys,its still an issue. Thanks Yosi for your suggestion but the issue is if the email is not a legitimate one though the format is correct. eg: if 'google@yahoo.com' is part of the mail list, then the mail function is failing without even sending mails to the others in the list.