# Send email to multiple recipients using mail function in php

Tags: php, email, for-loop

I am working on a project and I want to send mail to multiple people one by one. I don't want to waste time on sending mail one by one to each person , so is there any method using looping & php mail function so that it can be done ?

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047762/php-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-even-if-one-of-the-recepient-is-invalid?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Use an array to define the email addresses.An example is shown below:

```
<?php

    $contacts = array(
    "youremailaddress@yourdomain.com",
    "youremailaddress@yourdomain.com",
    //....as many email address as you need
    );

    foreach($contacts as $contact) {

    $to      =  $contact;
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    }

    ?>
```